# jQuery remove() is removing and then putting it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show what would be the equivalent of a read only form that you can close when you hit the close button. When I step through the debugger it appears that the dynamically appended elements are getting removed but then it steps into the jQuery file, into some method, and then puts it back as it was before hitting remove and I can't understand why.

```
var array=TodoItem.all;
$(document).ready(function() {
    initNoComplete(array);
    sortIt(array);
    $("#add").on("click",function(e)
    {
        $("#itemHolder").append($('<div class="newItem notDue">&nbsp</div>'));    
    });
    $("select").change(function()
    {
        sortIt(array);
    });
    $("#isComplete").change(function()
    {
        if($("#isComplete").is(":checked"))
        {
            init(array);
        }
        else
        {
            initNoComplete(array);
        }
    });
});
function createEditForm(h,array,i)
{

    $(h).append('<div id="editToDo">\
        <form id="editForm">\
         </form>\
         </div>');
    $("#editForm").append("Title:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<input>',{name:'title',type:'text',value:array[i].title}));
    $("#editForm").append("<br>Due Date:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<input>',{name:'due_date',type:'text',value:array[i].due_date}));
    $("#editForm").append("<br>Complete:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<input>',{name:'complete',type:'checkbox',value:array[i].complete}));
    $("#editForm").append("<br>Priority:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<input>',{name:'title',type:'text',value:array[i].priority}));
    $("#editForm").append("<br>Project:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<input>',{name:'project',type:'text',value:array[i].project}));
    $("#editForm").append("<br>Note:");
    $("#editForm").append($('<textarea>',{class:"note",name:"note", rows:5, cols:30}));
    $('.note').append(array[i].note);
    $("#editForm").append('<button class="submit">Submit</button>');
    $("#editForm").append('<button class="close">Close</button>');
}
function showForm(h,array,i)
{
    $(h).append('<div id="showForm"></div>');
        $("#showForm").append("Title:");
        $("#showForm").append(array[i].title);
        $("#showForm").append("<br>Due Date:");
        $("#showForm").append(array[i].due_date);
        $("#showForm").append("<br>Complete:");
        $("#showForm").append("<input type=checkbox name='checked'>");
        $("#showForm").append("<br>Priority:");
        $("#showForm").append(array[i].priority);
        $("#showForm").append("<br>Project:");
        $("#showForm").append(array[i].project);
        $("#showForm").append("<br>Note:");
        $('#showForm').append("<textarea readonly>"+array[i].note+"</textarea>");
        $("#showForm").append('<div><button class="submit" id="edit">Edit</button></div>');
        $("#showForm").append('<div><button class="close">Close</button></div>');
        $("#showForm").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
        prepareChildListeners();
}
function prepareListeners()
{
    $(".submit").on("click",function(e)
    {
        if(validateForm())
        {
            var title=document.forms["newForm"]["title"].value;
            var note=document.forms["newForm"]["note"].value;
            var project=document.forms["newForm"]["project"].value; 
            var due_date=document.forms["newForm"]["due_date"].value;
            var complete=$("#complete").prop('checked') ? 1 : 0 ;
            var priority=document.forms["newForm"]["priority"].value;
            var newToDo = new TodoItem(title, note, project, due_date, priority, complete);
            var test=document.getElementById('newForm');
            test.reset();
            $(".newToDo").toggle();
            sortIt(array);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".newItem").click(function()
    {
        $('#showForm').remove();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        showForm(this,array,id); 
    });

}
function prepareChildListeners()
{
    $(".close").click(function(e)
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        e.preventDefault();

    });
    $("#edit").click(function(e)
    {
        item = $('#edit').parent().parent().parent();
        $('#edit').parent().parent().remove();
        createEditForm($(item),array,$(item).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todo Item Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TodoViewer.css">
    <script src="/uncSemester7/comp426/a3/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="TodoItem.js"></script>
    <script src="TodoViewer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="list">
        <div class="button">
        Sort By:
            <select class="dropdown">
                <option value="Title">Title</option>
                <option value="Priority">Priority</option>
                <option value="DueDate">Due Date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button id="add">Add ToDo Item</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button" >
            Show Completed:<input type="checkbox" id="isComplete">
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="itemHolder"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not keeping a reference to the removed element so it can't be reinserted. It looks like you're creating new items that look mighty similar though. Check your logic.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a bare minimum code example?

Comment: Yeah I'll re-edit it, it's slightly overwhelming

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle next time. I think e.preventDefault() should be placed before everything else in your events. And if the removed element are inserted dynamically, maybe try this syntax : $(document).on('click', ".close", function(){}) instead of $(".close").click();

Comment: @FC'I would provide a working fiddle but it would require posting 4 files worth of info and a lot of unnecessary code that I thought people might not want to look at. What is the difference between the two methods you just listed?

Comment: you need to add `e.preventDefault();` to all of your button clicks otherwise your page will post back after the script has run (therefore reverting your page to what it was before).  The above code only has it for some button clicks

Comment: I added it on all clicks but the same behavior occurs